# PySpark, How to parse a string formated as a dict and append some key as new columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing a problem while reading a csv file with a curious column.

**Schema**

```
root
 |-- Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- Lon_tower: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Lat_tower: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Compagny: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Address_tower: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Assigned_band_1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Assigned_band_2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Assigned_band_3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Assigned_band_4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Assigned_band_5: string (nullable = true)
 |-- raw_geocode: string (nullable = true)
```

**raw_geocode sample**

```json
[{'road': 'Calle el Topo', 'residential': 'Los Sauces', 'hamlet': 'El Cardal', 'village': 'Los Sauces', 'city': 'San Andrés y Sauces', 'county': 'Santa Cruz de Tenerife', 'archipelago': 'Canarias', 'postcode': '38720', 'country': 'España', 'country_code': 'es'}]
```

I would like get the key as headers and fill the sparkdataframe with the value or Null if the key doesn't exist for this row. I don't want all the key but only some in a list. I removed the [ ' ]

An example to better understand:

```
myList = ['road', 'tourism', 'country_code']
|Id   |...|raw_geocode |
|1    |...|{road: Calle el Topo, archipelago: Canarias, postcode: 38720, country_code: es}
|2    |...|{tourism: Mirador Montaña El Molino, road: Mirador Montaña El Molino, village: Barlovento, country_code: es}
```

**Desired result**

```
|ID  |...|road          |tourism                   |country_code|
|1   |...|Calle el Topo |NULL                      |es
|2   |...|Null          |Mirador Montaña El Molino |es
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `regexp_extract` to extract the values desired:

```
myList = ['road', 'tourism', 'country_code']

for i in myList:
    df = df.withColumn(
        i, 
        F.when(
            F.regexp_extract('raw_geocode', i+': ([^,}]+)', 1) != "",
            F.regexp_extract('raw_geocode', i+': ([^,}]+)', 1)
        )
    )

df.show(truncate=False)
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|Id |raw_geocode                                                                                                 |road                     |tourism                  |country_code|
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
|1  |{road: Calle el Topo, archipelago: Canarias, postcode: 38720, country_code: es}                             |Calle el Topo            |null                     |es          |
|2  |{tourism: Mirador Montaña El Molino, road: Mirador Montaña El Molino, village: Barlovento, country_code: es}|Mirador Montaña El Molino|Mirador Montaña El Molino|es          |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick response, You make my day! Could you explain the` i+ `?

Comment: That's for adding the column name in the list dynamically to the regex pattern.